# Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga SD card not detected

Tags: drivers, lenovo, thinkpad, sd-card

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga 14 and nautilus doesn't detect my SD card with the built in SD car slot. The card is a SanDisk microSDXC UHS-l card with adapter.

output of `lspci -v`

```
...
02:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 01) 
Subsystem: Lenovo SD/MMC Card Reader Controller 
Physical Slot: 3 
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19   Memory at d2b01000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K] 
Memory at d2b00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K] 
Capabilities: <access denied> 
Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci 
Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
...
```

There is no model number for the card reader like there is in other [posts](https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/unbekannter-realtek-sd-kartenleser-einrichten-/)
So I don't know if I need to install Realtek drivers, or which one if I do.

output of `ls -la /dev/sd*` with the card in and out does not change.

not inserted & inserted

```
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 0 Sep 25 11:18 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 Sep 25 11:18 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 2 Sep 25 11:18 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 3 Sep 25 11:18 /dev/sda3
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 4 Sep 25 11:18 /dev/sda4
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 5 Sep 25 11:18 /dev/sda5
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 6 Sep 25 11:18 /dev/sda6
```

output of `sudo fdisk -l`

not inserted and inserted

```
...
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048    534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda2     534528    567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     567296 279813281 279245986 133.2G Microsoft basic dat
/dev/sda4  498069504 500117503   2048000  1000M Windows recovery en
/dev/sda5  279814144 481531903 201717760  96.2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  481531904 498069503  16537600   7.9G Linux swap
```

I'm such a noob so please give me some context for the three commands above. I got them from other posts about SD card reader problems but I'm not getting similar outputs (/dev/sd doesn't detect another device and lspci doesn't give me a device number for a driver) so I can't act on the direction of other posts.

The card works on windows partition of this laptop.